# Why is does my webview in my android not display my html file correctly?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an html file that displays an equation. The html file uses this library ( http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html ). In a web browser everything works fine. The problem is when i load that html file into my webview in my app. the actual html command in the body does not convert into an equation like it did in the web browser. What is the problem here?

I placed the html file and the jquery library in the assets folder in my app. The command to load the html file is:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/quadratic.html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling `Javascript` in the `WebView`

`someWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

and let us know if it works :)

Comment: Can you the contents of quatratic.html?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I forgot to set the correct path of the jquery libraries in the html document. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

have you enabled javascript on the webview?

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```